# Block public button when share on facebook

Tags: objective-c, facebook, share

Is it possible to disable the public button on the Facebook page so that users always share in public and they can't change it to only me.

Comment: I think it would be contrary to the Facebook legal terms: https://www.facebook.com/legal/terms

Comment: Please don’t build spam apps.

Answer (score 0):

No, you can't force the user to post something more widely than they want to

If you find a way to, you should submit it to [Facebook's whitehat program](https://www.facebook.com/whitehat/) and if it checks out you may get a cash bounty